# How to persist Azure Edge Stream definitions

Tags: azure, azure-sql-edge

As the title suggests, I‘m wondering how to persist stream definitions for streams that are created and deployed to an Azure Edge SQL instance.

My understanding is that an Azure Edge SQL instance may operate in isolation, and unless a backup or replication is maintained separately the data will be lost when the instance dies.

However, what about meta data and stream definitions? Is it possible to persist these with the „board Instruments“ provided by Azure Edge management?

For example, I want an edge node to be redeployed and setup streams and continue to process stream data, without requiring redefine the streams again.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Edge supports deployment of SQL Database dacpac (and bacpac) packages to create SQL Server Objects (like streaming jobs etc.) required as part of deployment. The dacpac package can be passed to the SQL Edge module by setting the `MSSQL_PACKAGE` environment variable as part of the deployment configuration. See [Using SQL Database DACPAC and BACPAC packages - Azure SQL Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/deploy-dacpac) for more details.